# Why are int, int64 etc not keywords in go? If they are predeclared identifiers, how would their declaration look like in the universal block?

Tags: go

Why are basic types such as int, string, int64 not keywords in Go?
I'm also wondering how the declaration of those keywords look like in universal block? Since, most of the go compiler is written go, how would the declaration be?

User declared variables look something like 
var i int

In case of basic go type, how would this be represented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a .go file for the universal block.  The block is intrinsic to the compiler.

It's impossible to write .go file describe the universal block. With the exception of the `error` type, the builtin types cannot be declared in terms of other Go types.  The builtin functions use features reserved to those functions and therefore cannot be written in Go. It's not [turtles all the way down](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtles_all_the_way_down) with the builtins.

The file [builtin.go](https://golang.org/src/builtin/builtin.go) documents the universal block. The file is not compiled.

Go prefers the universal block over keywords because declarations can be added to the universal block without breaking existing programs.